# Deleting and element by using a php id inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to do it so when a user checks a checkbox it gets the Email to a text field and when the user unchecks it it deletes the text field, here's the code that I've tried to use that's not working.
The php code:

```
<?php

        $execItems = $conn->query("SELECT Nome,EmailGeral,Enviado FROM escolas");

        while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array()){
            echo    "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$infoItems['Nome']."</td>
                        <td>".$infoItems['EmailGeral']."</td>
                        <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{$infoItems['EmailGeral']}\"".($infoItems['Enviado']?' checked':' ')." onclick=\"emailNextWithAddress(this, '".$infoItems['EmailGeral']."');\"/>
                    </tr>
                ";

        }
    ?>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
    function emailNextWithAddress(chk,address) {

        if(chk.checked === true){
            var nextEmail, inside_where;
            nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
            nextEmail.value = address;
            nextEmail.type = 'text';
            nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
            nextEmail.className = 'insemail';
            nextEmail.style.display = 'inline-block';
            inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
            inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
            return false;
        } else {
            var nextEmail, inside_where;
            nextEmail.value = address;
            nextEmail.className = 'delemail';
            inside_where = document.getElementById(<?php echo $infoItems['EmailGeral'] ?>);
            inside_where.parentElement.removeChild(nextEmail);
            return false;
        }

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `id` as the last parameter, and using it on your function :

```
<td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{$infoItems['EmailGeral']}\"".($infoItems['Enviado']?' checked':' ')." onclick=\"emailNextWithAddress(this, '".$infoItems['EmailGeral']."', this.id);\"/></td>



<script>
    function emailNextWithAddress(chk,address,id) {

        if(chk.checked === true){
            var nextEmail, inside_where;
            nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
            nextEmail.value = address;
            nextEmail.type = 'text';
            nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
            nextEmail.className = 'insemail';
            nextEmail.style.display = 'inline-block';
            inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
            inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
            return false;
        } else {
            var nextEmail, inside_where;
            nextEmail.value = address;
            nextEmail.className = 'delemail';
            inside_where = document.getElementById(id);
            inside_where.parentElement.removeChild(nextEmail);
            return false;
        }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

at least you're missing some quotes around that id

pick whether double/single vs single/double quotes:

- `document.getElementById("<?php echo $infoItems['EmailGeral'] ?>")`
- `document.getElementById('<?php echo $infoItems["EmailGeral"] ?>')`

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of php/html was missing a closing `</td>` tag after the checkbox.

The javascript function could, I believe, be simplified a little like this. I made an assumption here in that the new input element should be appended to the current table row - I could not determine what the element with id `addEmail` was or where it was. The below should append a new text field in the same cell as the checkbox, populate with the email address when checked and remove when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
<?php

    $execItems = $conn->query("SELECT Nome,EmailGeral,Enviado FROM escolas");

    while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array()){
        $name=$infoItems['Nome'];
        $email=$infoItems['EmailGeral'];
        $checked=$infoItems['Enviado'] ? 'checked' : '';

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$email</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' id='{$email}' {$checked} onclick='emailNextWithAddress( this );' /></td>
        </tr>";

    }
?>


<script>
    function emailNextWithAddress( chk ) {
        try{
            if( chk.checked === true ){
                var nextEmail;
                    nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
                    nextEmail.value = chk.id;
                    nextEmail.type = 'text';
                    nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
                    nextEmail.className = 'insemail';
                    nextEmail.style.display = 'inline-block';

                chk.parentNode.appendChild( nextEmail );
            } else {
                chk.parentNode.removeChild( chk.parentNode.querySelector('input[ name="email[]" ]') );
            }
            return false;
        }catch( err ){
            console.info( err.message )
        }
    }
</script>
```